# Session management in Angular 2 Spring Restful webservice

Tags: angular, session, session-cookies, spring-restcontroller

I am learning angular 2. I am trying to do session management in angular 2 and spring mvc. I found many articles on angular 1 but did not find any significant on angular2. I tried with withCredentials: true, but it did not work.

```
       var headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       headers.append( 'Accept', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
       let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials:true });
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllProducts', options).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe();
```

In product controller, I am trying to get session as follows.

```
public @ResponseBody List<Product> getAllProducts(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    System.out.println("Inside product controller");
    HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);
    List<Product> productList = Collections.emptyList();
    if (httpSession == null) {
        //TODO - Redirect to login page.
    } else {
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setDescription("Product1 Description");
        product.setName("Product1 Name");
        product.setPrice(BigDecimal.TEN);
        product.setSku("PRODUCT1_SKU");
        productList.add(product);
    }
```

But I am always getting session as null. I already created session in login controller and set the attribute in session as follows.

```
@ResponseBody public String login(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws JSONException {
    System.out.println("Inside Login Controller");
    if ("abc".equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUsername()) && "xyz".equals(user.getPassword())) {
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(true);
        httpSession.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    }
```

Comment: You solved this issue?

Comment: I moved to JWT token with Angular 2 and Spring boot